# Materialize Select Closes Automatically When Dropdown

Tags: php, jquery, select, dropdown, materialize

I have a form with several select with Materialize-JQuery but the problem I have is when I select or dropdown, the select hides automatically the first time. It's display the options until de second time and this happens always... What am I missing?

```
   <script>
       $(document).ready(function(){
           $('select').material_select();
           $('select').formSelect();
       });
   </script>
```

```
<div class="input-field col s3">
   <select class="validate" id="year">
      <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
      <option value="2020">2020</option>
      <option value="2021">2021</option>
      <option value="2022">2022</option>
      <option value="2023">2023</option>
   </select>
   <label>Select Year</label>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/56725559/16087059
Apparently it's a bug

Comment: For me this solution worked: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63100293/7907092 - Similar to the previous comment, just add timeout

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, why are you using two different inits?:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('select').material_select(); // This is from an older version of Materialize 
  $('select').formSelect(); // This is from 1.0.0
});
```

You just need one init, which will initialize ***all*** your select elements. From the [documentation](https://materializecss.com/select.html#initialization):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('select').formSelect();
});
```

Secondly, we really need to see a live working example of this.